# Elevation is increasing in list view

Tags: java, android, xml

I've read the same question about elevation, but not found answer for it

This elevation is increasing for every next item like this picture.

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginStart="6dp"
android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
android:layout_marginEnd="6dp"
android:layout_marginBottom="6dp"
android:background="@drawable/list_background"
android:elevation="3dp"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingBottom="5dp">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/urban_word"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:textAllCaps="true"
    android:textColor="@color/textColor"
    android:textSize="25sp"
    tools:text="Name" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/urban_def"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:maxLines="3"
    android:paddingStart="10dp"
    android:paddingEnd="10dp"
    android:paddingBottom="3dp"
    android:textColor="@color/infoColor"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    tools:text="Info" />
```

Comment: set programmatically and refresh listview.

Comment: Use CardView for elevation in Material Design component. by implementing `implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.1'`